# Where should I ask a question regarding copyrights?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, copyright

On which of the Stack Exchange site should I ask a question regarding copyrights?

Example question:

> Do I have the permission to include the content of a document in my website?
>
> The copyright in question is from the SWEBOK and the licence says:
>
> > This document may be copied, in whole or in part, in any form or by any means, as is, or with alterations, provided that (1) alterations are clearly marked as alterations and (2) this copyright notice is included unmodified in any copy.
>
> SWEBOK book copyright: http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok/html/copyright

Comment: If you take legal advice from strangers on the internet, you deserve whatever happens to you when you get sued later.

Comment: There are less dramatic scenarios. Maybe it's about licensing a toy program that I marginally care about. Worst-case result: somebody *might* abuse licensing holes, but they might do so even *with* a rock-solid license.

Comment: [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is now up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there are no Stack Exchange sites that cover copyrights or licensing *specifically*.

There was a proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51301/copyrights?referrer=bllUdnErZXVMZd2Nw4wT3Q2) that would have dealt with the topic but it has been deleted.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about technical writing and documentation copyright should be on topic on [Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Before you post your question, you should take some time to read the [site's help articles](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help) and search for similar questions, to make sure your question will be welcomed by the site's community.

Comment: From a quick glance at [writers.se], it doesn't seem to be the case. Most questions are from the point of view of a writer deciding the licensing of their work.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a closer look @AsheeshR, there are several questions about using copyrighted material in your own work. You'll find most of them under: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright. Couple of examples: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8694/how-to-use-creative-commons-materials & http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/permission-to-use-emails-from-famous-deceased-person

Answer (score 2):

You could ask that question at [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) because it deals with the law (clearly) and [copyrights](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) as well. In its [Help Center for on-topic topics](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it lists:

> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals